# Google Maps API 3 - Info Window Issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

What do I need to add & where - to make my markers popup the info window, using my var locations txt?

```
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>

var map;
var brooklyn = new google.maps.LatLng(48.1391265, 11.580186300000037);

var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';

function initialize() {


  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 2,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.1391265, 11.580186300000037),
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    panControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        styles: [ { stylers: [ { hue: "#098AAD" } ] } ]

  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
                                mapOptions);

  setMarkers(map, locations);
}

var locations = [
  ['Plano TX', 33.01984, -96.69889, 13],
  ['Hemel Hempstead UK', 51.75324, -0.44863, 12],
  ['Dubai', 25.27114, 55.30748, 11],
  ['San Francisco CA', 37.77493, -122.41942, 10],
  ['Chicago IL', 41.87811, -87.62980, 9],
  ['New York NY', 40.71435, -74.00597, 8],
  ['Troy MI', 42.60559, -83.14993, 7],
  ['Santa Monica CA', 34.01945, -118.49119, 6],
  ['St Peters MO', 38.78747, -90.62989, 5],
  ['Pittsford NY', 43.09062, -77.51500, 4],
  ['Las Vegas NV', 36.11465, -115.17282, 3],
  ['Haidian Beijing', 39.95991, 116.29805, 2],
  ['New Delhi', 28.63531, 77.22496, 1]
];

function setMarkers(map, locations) {

  var image = {
    url: 'images/marker-rmg.png',
    size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
  };

  var shape = {
      coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
      type: 'poly'
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var location = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location[1], location[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: location[0],
        zIndex: location[3]
    });
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
    <div id="map-canvas" style="height: 300px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a global variable (or within your `setMarkers` function), `infowindow`:

```
 var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: ""
        });
```

Then within your loop, call a new function, passing various parameters you'll require:

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var location = locations[i];
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location[1], location[2]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: location[0],
        zIndex: location[3]
    });

    bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, location[0]);
  }
```

Then create a new global function which binds the click event to markers and opens the infowindow with the specified content:

```
 function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, strDescription) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(strDescription);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
```

Update: here's the complete code I'd use

```
<script>
    var map;
    var brooklyn = new google.maps.LatLng(48.1391265, 11.580186300000037);

    var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';

    var locations = [
        ['Plano TX', 33.01984, -96.69889, 13],
        ['Hemel Hempstead UK', 51.75324, -0.44863, 12],
        ['Dubai', 25.27114, 55.30748, 11],
        ['San Francisco CA', 37.77493, -122.41942, 10],
        ['Chicago IL', 41.87811, -87.62980, 9],
        ['New York NY', 40.71435, -74.00597, 8],
        ['Troy MI', 42.60559, -83.14993, 7],
        ['Santa Monica CA', 34.01945, -118.49119, 6],
        ['St Peters MO', 38.78747, -90.62989, 5],
        ['Pittsford NY', 43.09062, -77.51500, 4],
        ['Las Vegas NV', 36.11465, -115.17282, 3],
        ['Haidian Beijing', 39.95991, 116.29805, 2],
        ['New Delhi', 28.63531, 77.22496, 1]
    ];

     function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, strDescription) {
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(strDescription);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }

    function setMarkers(map, locations) {
        var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: ""
        });
        var image = {
            url: 'images/marker-rmg.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
        };

        var shape = {
            coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
            type: 'poly'
        };

        var i, location, myLatLng, marker;

        for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
            location = locations[i];
            myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(location[1], location[2]);
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                shape: shape,
                title: location[0],
                zIndex: location[3]
            });

            bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infowindow, location[0]);
        }
    }

    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 2,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.1391265, 11.580186300000037),
            disableDefaultUI: true,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
            },
            zoomControl: true,
            panControl: true,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            styles: [ { stylers: [ { hue: "#098AAD" } ] } ]
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

        setMarkers(map, locations);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Duncan - could you possible add this (above) to my code? I seem to be struggling with it & it's not working (not a strong coder)

Comment: I've added more code, try that

Comment: Thanks Duncan... my be broken somewhere, as it's not showing the map at all :(

Comment: ignore that.... me being stupis - works great! thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind click event to your markers i.e after the markers are created you need to store them in an array. Then add the below code

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({       
    position: position  
});



var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content:"Any content or latitude longitude info"
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Here its bit tricky, i.e if there are multiple markers then you need build the `marker` variable accordingly. In your case may be you can append the for loop counter 'i' to the marker variable such as marker_+i and then fire the click event on those variables inside the same loop.